# Karate JavaAPITest - Specify feature call tag

Tags: karate

https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/java/JavaApiTest.java

We are planning to have Java API test(s) to execute karate features, we went through the above link and realised in-built library doesn't have an option to specify feature-call tag. As a work-around we extended the runner class and populated "tag" details to feature object.

Is it feasible to specify call tag while executing a feature from Java without extending the base runner class?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear - so you can try submit an open-source pull request. This is the right thing to do because it will help improve the framework if there really is a gap.